# Why do I get a dead code warning on my static logger

Tags: rust

I'm trying to follow the docs for [log](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/) to implement a logger. I have the following code:

**logger.rs**

```
use std::sync::OnceLock;

static LOGGER: OnceLock<Logger> = OnceLock::new();

struct Logger {
    level: log::Level,
}

pub fn init(level: log::Level) {
    if let Ok(_) = LOGGER.set(Logger { level }) {
        log::set_logger(LOGGER.get().unwrap()).unwrap();
        log::set_max_level(level.to_level_filter());
    }
}

impl log::Log for Logger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &log::Metadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= self.level
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &log::Record) {
        if self.enabled(record.metadata()) {
            eprintln!("{}: {}", record.level(), record.args());
        }
    }

    fn flush(&self) {}
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
use log::info;

mod logger;

pub fn run(loglevel: log::Level) {
    logger::init(loglevel);
    info!("hi");
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod logger;

fn main() {
    pbls::run(log::Level::Info);
}
```

`cargo build` gives me two warnings:

```
warning: static `LOGGER` is never used
 --> src/logger.rs:3:8
  |
3 | static LOGGER: OnceLock<Logger> = OnceLock::new();
  |        ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: function `init` is never used
 --> src/logger.rs:9:8
  |
9 | pub fn init(level: log::Level) {
  |        ^^^^
```

However, it seems that I am using logger. If I remove `LOGGER` or `init`, the code fails to compile. I know I can use `#[allow(dead_code)]` to ignore the warning, but why is it appearing? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in `rustc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `mod logger;` from `main.rs`.

Otherwise you're trying to declare that file twice (once from `lib.rs` and once from `main.rs`) but you aren't using the one from `main.rs` and thus getting the warnings about unused code.